# Align H2 and P on right side of I

Tags: html, css

I have the following Html and CSS [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/847ndaap/):

```
<div>
   <i class="fa fa-yelp"></i>
   <h2>Help</h2>
   <p>This is some text which I want to be on the right side of span</p>
</div>

div {width: 200px;}
i {
  font-size: 48px!important;
  float: left;
}
h2 {float: left;}
p {float: left;}
```

I need that h2 and p to be on a same column on the right of the i tag.

I am using floats but no luck. How can I do this without tables?

Comment: Your div is too narrow...remove the width. = http://jsfiddle.net/847ndaap/1/ - although `inline-block` might be a better option - http://jsfiddle.net/847ndaap/4/

Comment: It is narrow because I need it that way ... what I need is the paragraph text to split into different lines always on the right side of the I tag and under the Header

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You only need to remove float: left; from the p and it will do what you want, if I understood correctly. If you want the text from the p to start in that line and wrap around the two elements in the second line, it has to be done diferently. So, which one is it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired giving margin to the paragraph?

```
 p {float: left;
 margin-left:20px;
  margin-top:0px}
```

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATE **
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/847ndaap/13/

In this example I am floating the left div only, and letting the right div fall into place, but giving it a padding that matches the size of your left floated div (48px). Works like a charm. I am also using min/max-width to allow the responsive bits to work.

New CSS:

```
.main{
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    width: 48px;
}
.left i{
    font-size: 48px!important;
}
.right{
    padding-left: 48px;
    max-width: 152px;
}
```

-

-

**OLD:**

So what you need to do is give yourself a container to hold your inner floated content. Then use 2 divs inside, a left and right. The left will contain your icon and the right will contain your content. Floats nest if you don't contain them - you will also need to specify width of each side so don't forget that. You will need to use a clearfix on your main container - in this example I am using a basic overflow hidden fix.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/847ndaap/10/

New HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
        <i class="fa fa-yelp"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h2>Help</h2>
        <p>This is some text which I want to be on the right side of span</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

New CSS:

```
.main{
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    width: 48px;
}
.left i{
    font-size: 48px!important;
}
.right{
    width: 152px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I need it to be responsive so I need the icon to be always the same size but the text to get narrow. So giving the divs a fixed width is not an option.